# How to pass two enums values in a "command parameter" in Xaml and get those values in CS file

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Hi I want to pass two enum values from Xaml file and want to get those values. I made a class having two value variables and using that type. but I dont know how to pass that class object through Xaml.

Xaml file

```
<dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="PointsItem" Content="Points" RibbonStyle="Large"  Command="{Binding DrawStyleItemCommand}" >
            <dxb:BarButtonItem.CommandParameter>
              <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource xmlns:convertor.ModelPropertyConverter}">
                <Binding Source="{x:Static enums:ModelModes.somex}" />
                <Binding Source="{x:Static enums:StyleModes.somey}" />
              </MultiBinding>
            </dxb:BarButtonItem.CommandParameter>
          </dxb:BarButtonItem>
```

cs file

```
private DelegateCommand<object> _drawStyleItemCommand;
        public DelegateCommand<object> DrawStyleItemCommand
        {
            get { return _drawStyleItemCommand ?? (_drawStyleItemCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(StyleItem)); }
        }
     private void StyleItem(object parameter)
        {
            var values = (object[])parameter;
            var enum1 = (ModelModes)values[0];
            var enum2 = (DrawStyleModes)values[1];
        }
XModel Class

     public class XModelProperty
        {
            public XModelModes bMode { get; set; }
            public XStyleModes dStyle { get; set; }

            public XModelProperty(BoneModelModes _bMode,DrawStyleModes _dStyle)
            {
                bMode = _bMode;
                dStyle = _dStyle;

            }        
        }
```

Convertor Class

```
namespace Infra.Converter
{
    public class BoneModelPropertyConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return values.Clone();
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    } 
}
```

I am getting parse exception at this line `<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource xmlns:convertor.BoneModelPropertyConverter}">`

Answer (score 3):

You don't necessarily need that `XModelProperty` class. Instead you use `MultiBinding` to pass multiple enum values as command parameter. This could look something like this

In your XAML:

```
<Button Content="Click me" Command="{Binding DrayStyleItemCommand }">
  <Button.CommandParameter>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiValueConverter}">
      <Binding Source="{x:Static enums:StyleModes.Somex}" />
      <Binding Source="{x:Static enums:StyleModes.Somey}" />
    </MultiBinding>
  </Button.CommandParameter>
</Button>
```

Create a `MultiValueConverter` and add it as resource in your XAML:

```
public class MultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    return values.Clone();
  }

  public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

And then, in your ViewModel you can access your enums as follows

```
private DelegateCommand<object> _drawStyleItemCommand;
public DelegateCommand<object> DrawStyleItemCommand
{
  get { return _drawStyleItemCommand ?? (_drawStyleItemCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(StyleItem)); }
}

private void StyleItem(object parameter)
{
  var values = (object[])parameter;
  var enum1 = (StyleModes)values[0];
  var enum2 = (StyleModes)values[1];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create the object of `XModelProperty` directly in XAML and pass that as **CommandParameter**. As below:

```
 <Button.......
 <Button.CommandParameter>
     <local:XModelProperty bMode="A" dStyle="C" />
 </Button.CommandParameter>
```

And in the ViewModel you'll get the object directly without any conversion:

```
 Command = new RelayCommand(param => this.CommandAction(param));
    }


    public RelayCommand Command { get; set; }

    private void CommandAction(object param)
    {
        var xModelProperty = param as XModelProperty;
    }
```

**Define Converter:**

```
<local:NotBoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="NotBoolToVisibilityConverter" />


{Binding Converter={StaticResource NotBoolToVisibilityConverter}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have implemented as you have mentioned but getting an exception. I have edit mt question according to the present implementation.

Comment: @QT-ITK-VTK-Help what exception are you getting? N i think you have not defined the converter correctly. see my updated answer

Comment: @QT-ITK-VTK-Help but you don't need a converter, just make an object of XModelProperty  in XAML and pass that as a parameter. you don't need to create an extra class(converterr) for that.

Comment: Its working. Thank you. The problem was I was not taking a converter as a key in xaml file like this  <local:NotBoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="NotBoolToVisibilityConverter" />  . now I am getting these values in model file but i want to publish those values but  we can only  publish one values at a time . I way I got that make a class , do we have any other way where we dont need to make class .

Comment: @QT-ITK-VTK-Help well You have to make a OOP structure so that an object can be created in XMAL and passed between different layers. either it will be a class or a list of classes/objects. One thing i was thinking is why do you want to pass enum values from UI/XAMl. If you can post a new question where you can define the whole scenario that would be much better and helpful. looking forward for that. :) Feel free to accept the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

1) Create converter

```
public class MultiInOneConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
      public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
      {
         return values.Clone();
      }

      public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
      {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
      }
}
```

2) Create enum

```
public enum StyleModes
{
      Somex,
      Somey,
      Somez
}
```

3) Define converter in resources

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MultiInOneConverter x:Key="MultiInOneConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

4) Use all of it

```
<Button Content="WithConverter" Command="{Binding WithConverterCommand}">
            <Button.CommandParameter>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiInOneConverter}">
                    <Binding>
                        <Binding.Source>
                            <local:StyleModes>Somex</local:StyleModes>
                        </Binding.Source>
                    </Binding>
                    <Binding>
                        <Binding.Source>
                            <local:StyleModes>Somey</local:StyleModes>
                        </Binding.Source>
                    </Binding>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Button.CommandParameter>
</Button>
```