# How to use MultiBinding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, icommand, multibinding

I would like to pass two text parameters when a button is clicked. I used MultiBinding and that partially works but something's not quite right yet.

Converter:

```
 public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values.Clone();
    }
```

In my Command class I have those parameters but I don't know how to pass that to my class. I tried to pass array but didn't work.

```
public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    var values = (object[]) parameter;
    var login = (string) values[0];
    _execute(login);
}
```

Now the parameters are in `values[0]` and `values[1]`.

When I had just one parameter my class was looking like that:

```
    public TestViewModel()
    {
        firstButton= new RelayCommand((parameter) => FirstButtonClick(parameter));
    }

    private void LoginButtonClick(object login)
    {
        MessageBox.Show((string) login);
    }
```

Thank you in advance,
Regards!

Comment: this may help you if I'm understanding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35307590/how-to-pass-two-enums-values-in-a-command-parameter-in-xaml-and-get-those-valu

Comment: Definitely I had logical problem but now I get it. Thank you so much.